# Sending repeater in an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, mailmessage, htmltextwriter

I need to send a table obtained using a repeater in a mail, are there examples on how embed a repeater in a mail body? I'm using MailMessage to send the mail. I tried to implement this example:

```
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
    new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    MyRepeater.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    string emailContent = stringWrite.ToString();
```

but there's an error:

```
Control ''m_repeater_btn" of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with    runat=server.
```

Even if i put the tag form i get still an error, how should i put it?

this is my asp.net page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="ViewMySisters.aspx.cs"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid grey;" width="500">
            <tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid grey;">firstname</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid grey;">lastname</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid grey;">age</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid grey;">work experienes</td>

            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NAME")%></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FAMILY         NAME")%></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AGE")%></td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server"   Text=">>>>" OnCommand="btnDetails_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>

      <br />
<asp:Button ID="sendMail" runat="server" Text="send" OnClick="sendmail_Clicked" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to execute your page (not single repeater):

```
    private string LoadMailTemplate()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            this.Server.Execute(this, sw, false);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

where `this` is your page class.

2) Also you can put your repeater on the control. Here is code that execute control's body:

```
 public static string LoadMailTemplate(string templatePath)      
 {
                var page = new Page();
                Control myControl = page.LoadControl(templatePath);   
                var sb = new StringBuilder();    
                page.Controls.Add(myControl);

                using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
                {
                    page.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
                }

                return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Call:

```
string  emailBody = LoadMailTemplate("~/modules/eurolight/MailTemplates/OrderMailTemplate.ascx");
```

Comment: it is a path of the control. For example templatePath = "~/modules/eurolight/MailTemplates/OrderMailTemplate.ascx".
But first try to execute yor page (without using controls)

Comment: try first this code:

var sb = new StringBuilder();        

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            string emailBody = page.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
        }

Use 'this' instead of 'page'

Comment: it says: cannot implicitly convert type void to type string

Comment: how can I find the path of the control?

Comment: In your case you don't need a control path. You can try to execute your page inside your ViewMySisters.aspx.cs file:

 this.Server.Execute(this, sw, false);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23097/discussion-between-algreat-and-camilla)

Answer (score 0):

An email is not an asp.net page.  There for you are limited to flat HTML controls.  I change change the link button to an anchor tag and link it back to your web application and load the details based on query string.

Comment: do you know some examples on which I could give a look?

Comment: What are you looking or examples of? Litmus.com will give you what you can do in an email.

Answer (score 0):

You need this code:

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)

End Sub
```

Comment: Would be a good idea to explain where this code should go and why the user should use it